# ko is not defined Error in Chutzpah

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, requirejs, chutzpah

I'm trying to write Unit Testing for my SPA project. Where we have used the `Durandal (Framework), Knockout (Binding) with RequireJs`.

I have installed the Chutzpah in Visual Studio 2012.

When i run my Test for the View Model, it throws me below error, even though the knockout js and other js are loaded correctly.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ko is not defined

***My Json Config Code:***

```
{
    "Framework": "jasmine",
    "TestHarnessReferenceMode": "AMD",
    "TestHarnessLocationMode": "SettingsFileAdjacent",
    "References" : [
        {"Path" : "../Scripts/require.js" },
        {"Path" : "config.js" }
    ],
    "Tests" : [
      {"Path": "tests"}
    ]
}
```

***My Config Js Code:***

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'text': '../Scripts/text',
        'durandal': '../Scripts/durandal',
        'plugins': '../Scripts/durandal/plugins',
        'jquery': '../Scripts/jquery-2.1.4',
        'knockout': '../Scripts/knockout-3.3.0'
    },

    shim: {

    }
});
```

***My FirstTest.Js Code:***

```
define(['project/modules/Settings/Subscriber/Viewmodels/Channels'],
    function (nChannel) {
        describe("Get Channels", function () {
            it("will check the Get Channels call and result", function () {
                var disp = nChannel.getChannels().then(function () {
                    var actualResult = ko.toJS(nChannel.Channels);
                    expect(actualResult.length).toEqual(3);
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

***ViewModel Code:***

```
define(['plugins/dialog'], function (dialog) {
    var subscriberList = ko.observableArray(); //Getting Error here - while loading the Js for Unit Testing

    var JsQ = $; //Getting JQUERY members here. // Works good.

    //Other Logics goes here

    return {
        subscriberList : subscriberList,
        JsQ : JsQ 
    };
});
```

The Configuration for the Jquery works perfect, since knockout also same as that. But gives error.

*Any Idea's / Suggestion why the error?*

Do i need to load the ko (knockout) separately?

***Edit 1:***

I have tried changing the `knockout` to `ko` it gives me the error `Uncaught Error: Script error for: knockout`.

***Edit 2:***

The problem i'm facing when i apply this solution, those existing code file needs the massive changes and the file counts are in hundreds. From `Init.Js` we have loaded the Jquery and Knockout. Like below.

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'text': '../Scripts/text',
        'durandal': '../Scripts/durandal',
        'plugins': '../Scripts/durandal/plugins'
    }
});

define('jquery', [], function () {
    return jQuery;
});

define('knockout', [], function () {
    return ko;
});
```

So inside any viewmodel we can get the instance of `knockout as ko`, without declaring the require js stuff in each veiwmodel for the Knockout (As you suggested).

But when i try the same in Chutzpah declaration this is not working. Not sure why.

Hope you understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both modules you show in your question, you use `ko` but you do not list `knockout` in your list of dependencies. This is a sure way to get the error you got. Modify your modules to list `knockout` in the dependencies, and add a corresponding parameter to the callback you give to `define`. For instance,

```
define(['knockout', 'plugins/dialog'], function (ko, dialog) {
```

Comment: Thanks your answer is very helpful. Please take a look at my Edit #2.